# How to multiply a pandas data frame by group?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with a group column and features:

| group | feature 1 | feature 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| A | 2 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| B | 2 | 1 |

And a multiplier table, with a multiplying constant for each group and feature:

| group | feature 1 | feature 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| B | 3 | 4 |

I have defined the first table as data and the second as multiplier. I try the following code:

```
data2 = data.copy()
for i in range(len(multipliers)):
    mul  = multipliers[features].loc[i]
    all_data2.loc[all_data2.group==i,features] = all_data2.loc[all_data2.group==0,features]*mul
```

Where I expect to get:

| group | feature 1 | feature 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| A | 2 | 2 |
| B | 3 | 4 |
| B | 6 | 4 |

(each feature and each group is multiplied by the corresponding value).

The code appear to work. But as I work with way bigger data sets the calculation are excruciatingly slow. Any way to proceed faster ?

Comment: Pandas indexing comes in handy here

Answer (score 3):

You can set `group` as index in both dataframes as suggested by @sammywemmy:

```
>>> data.set_index('group').mul(multipliers.set_index('group')).reset_index()

  group  feature 1  feature 2
0     A          1          2
1     A          2          2
2     B          3          4
3     B          6          4
```

Obviously, I assume your group and features are unique in `multipliers` dataframe.

A relevant note from @mozway:

> But you'll eventually lose the original index

If you want to preserve the index, you can use:

```
out = (data.set_index('group', append=True)
           .mul(multipliers.set_index('group'), level='group')
           .reset_index(level='group'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Align with a left-[`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and multiply:

```
data[['feature 1', 'feature 2']] *= (data[['group']].merge(multipliers, how='left')
                                     [['feature 1', 'feature 2']].to_numpy()
                                    )
```

Modified dataframe:

```
  group  feature 1  feature 2
0     A          1          2
1     A          2          2
2     B          3          4
3     B          6          4
```